# Knife list kernel version in an environment

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

I am trying to find the command to list the kernel version for each node in an environment.

The following command only list the nodes but not the kernel version.

```
knife search node 'chef_environment:production'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
knife search node 'chef_environment:production' -a kernel.release
```